# Is there an event I can listent to that takes place after a form submit and after the form has been verified with HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this form:

```
   <div id="account-form">
        <form action="/Account/Login" id="login-form" class="form" method="post">
            <div id="input-fields">
                <div>
                    <input class="data-entry medium-margin" id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="Username (or guest)" required="required " size="25" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="data-entry medium-margin" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password (or guest)" required="required " size="25" type="password">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="data-entry inline-checkbox" id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false">
                    <p style="margin-top: 0;">Remember me?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="data-entry medium" id="login" type="submit">Login</button>
            <button class="data-entry medium" id="register" type="button" onclick="location.href='/Account/Register'">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and this javascript that disables the inputs after the form submit.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0]
            .addEventListener("submit", function () {
                var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("data-entry");
                for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    inputs[i].disabled = true;
                }
    })();
</script>
```

When I enter login data and then click submit the inputs are disabled and the submit verification fails saying that the input fields are not filled out.

Is there some way I can disable the input fields after HTML5 verification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just schedule a callback with a timeout of 0

```
.addEventListener("submit", function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("data-entry");
        for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }, 0); });
```

This way the disabling code will be executed once the `submit` event processing has been completed. You will have however to re-enable the fields in case the verification fails otherwise the user will not be able to correct the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. You mention "once the submit event processing has been completed". Does this mean after the server has returned a response to the submit or just after the submit verification has completed?

Comment: @Melina: For a regular "web 1.0" form the result of submission will actually replace the current page so the discussion about what happens after the response is received is nonsense (the current world would have been ended by then). Not sure if this is stated in the specs but looking at browsers behavior my suspect is that submission is still asynchronous and you can interact with the page while waiting the reply. For an ajax post the disabling is done immediately after submission and before receiving the reply.